# Error:Execution failed for task ':lib:compileReleaseAidl'. > Executor Singleton not started

Tags: java, android, github, android-studio

When I import one project into my Android Studio from Github, this happens. How to fix it?

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources, :lib:generateDebugSources, :lib:generateDebugTestSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:lib:compileLint
:lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preBuild
:lib:preReleaseBuild
:lib:checkReleaseManifest
:lib:preDebugBuild
:lib:preDebugTestBuild
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:lib:compileReleaseAidl FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':lib:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Executor Singleton not started
```

Answer (score 32):

I was facing the same issue, here is what I did:

1- Updated all the project dependencies to latest version (AppCompat,SupportV4,cardview, etc) which are **22+**

2- Updated root projects **build.gradle** file to use latest gradle version :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

3- In **gradle-wrapper.properties** file I used the latest gradle version which is **2.4**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Comment: This helped me out a ton once I upgraded to Android Studio 1.3

Comment: I had this problem after upgrading android studio.Just updating the classpath as you have in step 2 fixed it - thanks

Comment: TKS. , i updated root project build.grade to use latest grade version : 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Answer (score 7):

I had in build.gradle :
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

I changed to :
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

The gradle wrapper should be in the same version as the gradle dependency.

The latest to this date is, in build.gradle

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

And, in gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.7-rc-1-all.zip