# Exception after upgrading to Android Studio 141.1972460

Tags: android, android-studio, upgrade

I upgraded my Android Studio yesterday to the latest version 141.1972460. After the upgrade, I used my old project configurations. Ever since, I have been trying to clean and rebuild my projects in the upgraded version but I keep getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> Executor Singleton not started
```

I have seen this problem for the first time. I tried to search how to resolve it, but I could not find anything on the internet. Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315693/errorexecution-failed-for-task-libcompilereleaseaidl-executor-singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that I was using Android plugin version 1.0.0 which is not compatible with Gradle version 2.4 (which happened after the upgrade). The issue was solved after I upgraded my Android plugin version to 1.2.0